# Anyone have file structure documentation for Windows Live Mail contacts.edb file?

Tags: email, contacts, file-format, windows-live, file-structure

Does anyone have any documentation or info on the file structure of the `contacts.edb` file as it is used in Windows Live Mail? I can't seem to find any way to import file back into WLM (I'm told it HAS no way, and must be "backed up" via manual exports to CSV files).

Given the apparent lack of means to reimport a backed up EDB file, I figured that perhaps I could just write a program to read all the contacts out into vcards or something, and then import those. (I'm actually looking ultimately to get them into Outlook, and ditch WLM for this user, cuz I don't feel like dealing with these maintenance headaches).

Problem is that I cannot find anywhere any information on the file format/structure for WLM's EDB files.

Thanks in advance, any help GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone finding this in the future, **THIS CAN BE DONE**, without needing to code anything! Use this program - [EseDbViewer](http://www.woanware.co.uk/?page_id=89) - to export the file to a CSV file, and then you can import that where ever you want.

Note that you pretty much need the whole file structure containing the `edb`, **not** *just* the `edb` file.

Hat-tip to [@MicrosoftHelps](https://twitter.com/#/MicrosoftHelps) on twitter.